# Java switch double duplicate case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm creating a chess game with java.

As you know when you start out the chess game you have two of each "Captains" (sorry I'm not sure what the term is) I have created the following switch case to create the graphical layout of the figures:

```
 switch (j) {
            case 1 || 8 : Rook tower = new Rook(""); return tower.getBrik();
            case 2 || 7 :
            case 3 || 6 : Bishop bishop = new Bishop(""); return bishop.getBrik();
            case 4      : King king = new King(""); return king.getBrik();
            case 5      : Queen queen = new Queen(""); return queen.getBrik();
 }
```

Where the getBrik() method is a Node that returns an imageview.

Now as you can see my case 2 and 3 are my failed attempt to do two cases in one.

Is this even possible and if so how?

Comment: The horse is called Knight ;) see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because of *fall through* (execution continues to the next `case` statement unless you put a `break;` at the end, or of course, as in your case, a `return`), you can just put the cases under each other:

```
...
case 1:
case 8:
    Rook tower = new Rook("");
    return tower.getBrik();
case 3:
case 6:
    Bishop bishop = new Bishop("");
    return bishop.getBrik();
...
```

Comment: So what is best pratice? nested if or duplicate cases?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: In your case, I would definitely say that `switch` is the best practice. Fall through is a bit dangerous sometimes (it is easy to forget a `break` and misinterpret the logic), but in simple cases like this that isn't a concern.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried OR by putting ||, but in switch case statements you cant use this operator. Therefore you just use if

```
if(j==1 || j==8){
 Rook tower = new Rook("");
            return tower.getBrik();
}else if(j==2 ||j==7 || j==6 || j==7){

Bishop bishop = new Bishop("");
            return bishop.getBrik();
}
.
.
.
```